# Does "Pursue Impossible" Make Grammatical Sense?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality

My university recently pushed a campaign for their new rebrand, and their tagline is "Pursue Impossible". I have seen a few adjectives used as nouns before but all had a definite article in front.

Surely my university isn't so stupid so as to make such an elementary grammatical mistake, so I ask if there is any way in which this tagline makes grammatical sense?

Either by some hidden rule, archaic form, or otherwise.

[Here's the campaign too if it helps shed light](http://www.pursueimpossible.uwa.edu.au)

Comment: Idiomatically it is usually expressed as *Pursue the impossible*. Without the article it is not grammatical.

Comment: I makes sense.  You just have to read "impossible" as a concept, not the usual part of speech.

Comment: I'm afraid your university is capable of more stupidity than you assumed. Or perhaps it's the ad agency that (as usual) cares more about layout than text and the sin of the university is restricted to giving it too quick a nod. Oh, and I don't like "fitting to its students" either. @HotLicks: Well yes, ad agencies are always talking about "concepts" rather than writing English, aren't they? We don't have to encourage the creatures.

Comment: @DavidPugh I also dislike "short-video message," which strikes me as just bizarre.

Comment: @HotLicks never mind that the usual label for that concept would be "impossibility."

Comment: it's clever - pursue the impossible, i.e. get pursue impossible as acceptable

Comment: Blame Apple for their _Think Different_ campaign.

Comment: @NeilW More likely Adidas' *Impossible is nothing*.

Comment: As a graduate of this University, and a one who encourages originality, I nevertheless find this slogan to be an embarrassment. Impact may well be judged by shock value, but here the impact is decidedly negative. One might even read the slogan as suggesting that pursuit is impossible...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you might pursue an adjective.

It sounds the same as

> Pursue yellow
>
> Pursue tall

I think it is a error in judgment on their part. In pursuit for brevity, they didn't realize what they came up with doesn't make sense. It is a shame because it looks like someone put a lot of effort on that website design.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it make grammatical sense?

Maybe, if you interpret "impossible" as a concept, as suggested by @HotLicks.  It is, however, a marketing slogan, and as such the more important question might be "will it be effective?"  A successful and influential marketing slogan doesn't have to be grammatically correct, for example:

> **Got Milk?** is one of the most famous commodity brand and influential
> campaigns in the United States.
>
> In an interview in Art & Copy, a 2009 documentary that focused on the origins of famous advertising slogans, Jeff Goodby and Rich Silverstein said that the phrase almost didn't turn into an advertising campaign. According to the New York Times, people at Goodby, Silverstein "thought it was **lazy, not to mention grammatically incorrect**".
> <sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Got_Milk%3F)</sub>

The inspiration for that slogan might be [Arthur C. Clarke's second law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws)

> The only way of discovering the limits of the possible is to **venture** a
> little way past them into the **impossible**.
> <sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws)</sub>

All emphasis mine.

#### Opinion:

The slogan strikes me as clever, but not memorable.  It lacks emotion.  In [Long Slogans Are Absolutely, Positively More Effective Than Short Ones](http://adage.com/article/al-ries/long-slogans-absolutely-positively-effective-short/145755/) the author makes the case for memorable slogans, not necessarily short taglines: memorable slogans have emotion and are usually long - "Got Milk?" campaign notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like they were going for "Pursue the impossible" but wanted to make it shorter--which also makes it grammatically incorrect.

However, if they had chosen "Pursue impossibilities" instead, that would have been grammatically correct *and* pithy.